# I want to target the last item of a grid if there are odd number of items in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, grid

I'm actually trying to build a WP theme with a grid system for my online portfolio. Does anyone know how to target the last item in the grid if there are odd numbers of item? I thought I could make the last one full width so there is no blank space... Thank you for helping me, let me know if you know the answer

```
<section class="grid">
    <div class="item" style="background: url('img/1.png') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: url('img/2.png') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: url('img/4.png') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: url('img/3.png') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>
</section>
```

I wanted to target the last-child only if I have like 3, 5, 7 projects only.

Comment: Do show us some effort you have put in code.

Answer (score 0):

In a CSS fashion, you can wrap your grid items in a parent wrapper, then specify the [`:last-child` psuedo-selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) to target that last child item (regardless of odd or even).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#wrap div:nth-child(2n+1):last-child {
  ...
}
```

For JavaScript, just use that as selector in `document.querySelector()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but to discover whether you've an odd number of array elements...

```
if ( ( a.length & 1 ) == 1 )
{
    // set width to 100%
}
```